# error PYRO0260 : Product 'xxxxx': Table 'CreateFolder'

Tags: wix

We are introducing a new component in a WiX patch and encountered the below error-

error PYRO0260 : Product 'xxxxx': Table 'CreateFolder' has a new row 'SampleDir/SampleServiceComp' added. This makes the patch not uninstallable.
pyro.exe : error PYRO0261 : This patch is not uninstallable. The 'Patch' element's attribute 'AllowRemoval' should be set to 'no'.

We have always been setting AllowRemoval='yes' in our Patch.wxs for our cumulative patches but never introduced a new feature in a Patch.

Can we add a new component in a Patch.msp, without setting the AllowRemoval='no'?

I could hardly find any documentation about the problem. Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are telling you that you can't add a `CreateFolder` row in a patch and have it still be uninstallable. That's covered in the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstallable-patches#patches-that-are-not-uninstallable). You can add a new component and/or feature in a patch, but if it contains a new row in the `CreateFolder` table, it can't be uninstalled; that's a limitation of Windows Installer.